# req.body is undefined when use router.post() but visible when use app.post()

Tags: node.js, express, undefined, req

I have the next `app.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const app = express();

app.use(`$/api/auth`, authRoutes)

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

module.exports = app;
```

And `routes/auth.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register",  (req, res) =>{
    res.status(200).json(req.body);
})
```

So, if I try to take `req.body` in auth.js, I get `undefined`, and if i pass any json instead of req.body, it will work fine.

Also if I'll move `post` to `app.js`, and it will look like this:

```
const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
    const app = express();
    
    // app.use(`$/api/auth`, authRoutes)
    
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

    app.post("/api/auth/register", (req, res) =>{
        res.status(200).json(req.body)
    })
     
    module.exports = app;
```

it also will work fine. What don't I see?

Comment: You installed your bodyparser after installing the route. Install it before the route. Note tha the bodyparser is just a middleware, nothing special.

Comment: Alternatively this will also work: `app.use('$/api/auth', bodyParser.json(), bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}), authRoutes)` - and means the same thing: install the bodyparser before the route. Only this way it is not global and is only installed for the route. Remember, bodyparser is just a regular middleware, nothing special.

Comment: @slebetman thanks a lot. still can't get used to they must have a certain order

Comment: It's easy. All middlewares are processed in the order you installed them. Nothing complicated. Express just creates a stack/list of them and process them one at a time. Also, endpoints are just middlewares that don't call `next()`. Express only has middlewares. It does not have anything that's not a middleware. Everything is a middleware.

Comment: Another example. If you have two endpoints `/hello/world` and `/hello/:message` you **MUST** install `/hello/world` first because `/hello/world` also matches `/hello/:message` where the string `world` is saved as `req.params.message`

Comment: Why are there no exported modules in your `routes/auth.js` file?

Comment: @xgqfrms Here are parts of files. I was so focused that forgot to add export, my bad

Comment: @slebetman I understand it and forget to check sometimes. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Slebetman in comments gave the answer.

So as contents of `app.use()` are middleware they depends on an order in which it disposed. Therefore I should have put lines with `bodyParser` above routing middleware.